# ¿Añadir datos en varias tablas con sql y php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El problema que tengo es que yo añado unos datos en una tabla el cual el id es autoincrementable, y me gustaria que ese id se añadiera a otra tabla relacionada junto con otro id, para ser mas específico dejo una foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente yo quiero meter datos en la tabla errands y que se añada el id de la tabla errands a la errandslink junto al id del grupo(que este lo tendría en una variable de php). Son tablas relacionadas

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$nameErrand = $_POST['nameErrand'];
$groupId = $_POST['groupId'];

$consulta="insert into errands values(null,'".$nameErrand."', null, null)";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

?>

ese a sido mi intento obviamente lo que hace es añadir datos a la tabla errands, la variable de groupid pasa un integer

Este es el segundo intento con la primera respuesta, pero al tener que implementar todo en un archivo no a funcionado

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$nameErrand = $_POST["nameErrand"];
$groupId = $_POST["groupId"];
$sr = 0;

$consulta1 = "insert into errands values(null,'".$nameErrand."', null, null)";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1) or die (mysqli_error());


$consulta2="SELECT max(errandId) as id from errands";
$nr = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2) or die (mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($nr);
$sr = $row["id"];


$consulta3="insert into errandslink values(".$groupId.", ".$sr.")";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta3) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Triggers puede ser la respuesta

Comment: Coincido con @BetaM, pásanos el intento que hayas hecho, así como el dataset para reproducir el problema y concrétanos qué contendría la variable de php. Datos de ejemplo vendrían genial para ayudarte.

Comment: e añadido mi codigo de php

Comment: Hay necesidad en tener el campo id de la tabla errands como autoincremental? Pienso que puedes evitar todo este inconveniente manejando en el mismo insert los id de las tablas errands y errandslink, es decir, no utilizar el campo id de errands como autoincremental sino que manejes estos id desde la aplicacion, al igual como lo haces con el id de la tabla groups

Comment: Si es totalmente necesario y perdon por haber olvidado decir que el de los grupos tambien es autoincremental, simplemente tengo el id del grupo porque lo obtengo de una forma diferente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo sustituir el `SELECT MAX` por `mysqli_insert_id`, no vayas a tener dos ejecuciones simultáneas y termines asignándoles el mismo `errandId` a ambas:

```
<?php

$_POST['nameErrand']='test';
$_POST['groupId']=1;

include 'conexion.php';
$nameErrand = $_POST["nameErrand"];
$groupId = $_POST["groupId"];
$sr = 0;

$consulta1 = "insert into errands values(null,'".$nameErrand."', null, null)";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta1) or die (mysqli_error());

/*
$consulta2="SELECT max(errandId) as id from errands";
$nr = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2) or die (mysqli_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($nr);
$sr = $row["id"];
*/

$sr=mysqli_insert_id($conexion);

$consulta3="insert into errandslink values(".$groupId.", ".$sr.")";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta3) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Facilito el dataset para realizar las comprobaciones del código:

```
CREATE TABLE groups(
  groupId int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  groupName varchar(30)
  );
CREATE TABLE errands(
  errandId int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  errandName varchar(30),
  username varchar(30),
  `date` date
  );
CREATE TABLE errandslink(
  groupId int,
  errandId int,
  FOREIGN KEY(groupId) REFERENCES groups(groupId),
  FOREIGN KEY(errandId) REFERENCES errands(errandId)
  );
INSERT INTO groups (groupName) VALUES ('Grupo 1');
```

Al menos yo no he tenido problemas con el tiempo de ejecución de tu código. De ser así, indícamelo en los comentarios o amplía tu pregunta indicando los mensajes de error o resultados no deseados que obtienes. Así como si necesitas resolverlo mediante un disparador en MysQL en vez de desde PHP.

Comment: A funcionado perfectamente, de esta forma no hay problemas con el tiempo de ejecución, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea lo mas optimo pero podrías usar un INSERT normal luego de que se haya insertado inmediatamente después con un "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" puedes capturar el ultimo id generado para la tabla errands y lo mismo para rellenar la tabla groups. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Si añades un ejemplo en código será más clara y aplicable la propuesta

Comment: Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), así te das una idea de las normas de la comunidad para dar respuestas de calidad y evitar que sean eliminadas.

Comment: Habria funcionado pero no es capaz de procesar la información lo suficientemente rapido para que funcione